# how to retrieve data of a particular row from the database

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

Im wandering from last few days and unable to complete how to retrieve data of a particular row from the database once i click on the view detail button from the main page. **[s_no is unique]**

**Here is my main page;**
**view.php**

```
    <?php
  include('dbconnect.php');
   $select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forms order by s_no desc");
   $i=1;
  while($userrow=mysql_fetch_array($select))

  {
  $s_no=$userrow['s_no'];
  $title_pro=$userrow['title_pro'];
  $institute=$userrow['institute'];
  $email=$userrow['email'];
  $contact=$userrow['contact'];
   $date=$userrow['date'];
?>
<p align="center"><a href="submit_pro.php">View Paginated</a></p>
 <div class="display">
  <p> S.No : <span><?php echo $s_no; ?></span>
  <p>   Title of the proposal: <span><?php echo $title_pro; ?></span>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $s_no; ?>" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this 
Record?');">
            <span class="delete" title="Delete"> X </span></a>
  </p>
  <br />
  <p> Institute: <span><?php echo $institute; ?></span>
    <a href="table_print.php?id=<?php echo $s_no; ?>"><span class="edit" 
title="Edit"> VIEW DETAIL</span></a>
  </p>
  <br />
  <p> Email: <span><?php echo $email; ?></span>
  </p>
  <br />
  <p> Contact name and address: <span><?php echo $contact; ?></span>
  </p>
  <br />
  <p> SUBMITTED ON : <span><?php echo $date; ?></span>
  </p>
  <br />
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

This main page (view.php) works fine. Now. once i click on the view detail button on the view.php(main page) it should view the all detail of the particular row.
Below is the table_print(detail page) code which is incomplete that i could not do it .

**Second page: table_print.php**

```
  <?php

  $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
  $mysql_user = "root";
  $mysql_password ="";
  $mysql_database = "iaoform_db";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
   $id = $_GET['id']; //read id from get inputs
   $sqli = "SELECT s_no, title_pro, type, cycle, type_pro, thesis, year, 
            proposer, institute, 
            email,present,contact,abstract,status_ongoing,status_file,
         sch_request,no_night,no_night_impossible,just_request,mode_ob,
          brief_descrip,plan,hfosc_b,hfosc_n,hfosc_g,hfosc_s,hesp_r,hesp_o,
      tirspec_b,tirspec_n,tirspec_s,tirspec_c,tirspec_slits,obj_name,obj_ra,
       obj_dec,obj_epoch,obj_mag,obj_size,scient_just,date,   

      status FROM forms WHERE s_no = ?"; //add a where clause with place 
                                         holder
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqli); 
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); //bind input parameters
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result();
    /* Get the number of rows */
   $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

   /* Bind the result to $row variable */
   $stmt->bind_result($row);

    if($num_of_rows < 1){  //exit or send the result if number of rows is less than one 
        echo "Can't find any record!"; 
        mysqli_close($conn);    
        exit();
    } { 
    ?>
 <!---------------------------------------------------->
 <?php
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {



 <table class="tg">
   <tr>
     <th class="tg-9hbo">S.No</th>
     <th class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["s_no"]; ?>   </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="tg-9hbo">Title of the proposal:</td>
     <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["title_pro"]; ?>   
 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="tg-9hbo">Type:</td>
     <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["type"]; ?>   </td>
   </tr>
   |
   |
   | 
   |
   |
   <tr>
     <td class="tg-9hbo">Submission date:</td>
     <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["date"]; ?>   </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
       /* free results */
       $stmt->free_result();

    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

Its will be very grateful to complete this. Thank a lot in advance ...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WHERE clause in your query to fetch specific row. The id comes in `$_GET` array. And using prepared statement with placeholder is needed to prevent sql injection. Try following code

```
    <?php

      $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
      $mysql_user = "root";
      $mysql_password ="";
      $mysql_database = "iaoform_db";

     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 
     $id = $_GET['id']; //read id from get inputs
     $sqli = "SELECT s_no, title_pro, type, cycle, type_pro, thesis, year, 
     proposer, institute, 
     email,present,contact,abstract,status_ongoing,status_file,

     sch_request,no_night,no_night_impossible,just_request,mode_ob,
     brief_descrip,plan,hfosc_b,hfosc_n,hfosc_g,hfosc_s,hesp_r,hesp_o,
     tirspec_b,tirspec_n,tirspec_s,tirspec_c,tirspec_slits,obj_name,obj_ra,
     obj_dec,obj_epoch,obj_mag,obj_size,scient_just,date,   

        status FROM forms WHERE s_no = ?"; //add a where clause with place holder
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqli); 
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); //bind input parameters
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* Get the number of rows */
       $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

       /* Bind the result to $row variable */
       $stmt->bind_result($row);

        if($num_of_rows < 1){  //exit or send the result if number of rows is less than one 
            echo "Can't find any record!"; 
            mysqli_close($conn);    
            exit();
        } { ?>
     <!---------------------------------------------------->
     <?php
        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {  ?>

     <table class="tg" id="myModal">
       <tr>
         <th class="tg-9hbo">S.No</th>
         <th class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["s_no"]; ?>   </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Title of the proposal:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["title_pro"]; ?>   
     </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Type:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["type"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Number of cycles/nights:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["cycle"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Type of the proposal:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["type_pro"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Title of the thesis:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["thesis"]; ?>   </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Expected year of thesis submission:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["year"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="6">List of Proposer:</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2">Proposer</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Institute</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Email</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2">Present</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["proposer"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["institute"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["email"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["present"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Contact name and address:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["contact"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Abstract:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["abstract"]; ?>   </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2">Status of ongoing / Previous 
     proposal</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="4">Attached file</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["status_ongoing"]; ?>   
           </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4"><?php echo $row["status_file"]; ?>   
      </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="tg-9hbo">Scheduling request:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["sch_request"]; ?>   
      </td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="6">No. of nights requested</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="2">Preferred dates</td>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="4">Impossible date</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["no_night"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4"><?php echo $row["no_night_impossible"]; 
     ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Justification for scheduling request:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["just_request"]; ?>   
      </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Instrument:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["instru1"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Mode of Observation:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["mode_ob"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Brief description of observations:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["brief_descrip"]; ?>   
     </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Plans for data reduction and analysis:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["plan"]; ?>   </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="6">HFOSC</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2">Broad Band Filters</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Narrow Band Filters</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Grisms</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2">Slits</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["hfosc_b"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["hfosc_n"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["hfosc_g"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["hfosc_s"]; ?>   </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="6">HESP</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="2">Resolution</td>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="4">Observation mode</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["hesp_r"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4"><?php echo $row["hesp_o"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="6">TIRSPEC</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Broad Band Filters</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Narrow Band Filters</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Single Order Dispersers</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Cross Dispersers</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo" colspan="2">Slits</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo"><?php echo $row["tirspec_b"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["tirspec_n"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["tirspec_s"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["tirspec_c"]; ?>   </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2"><?php echo $row["tirspec_slits"]; ?>   
     </td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-amwm" colspan="6">List of objects: (essential)</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Name</td>
        <td class="tg-9hbo">RA (hh mm ss)</td>
        <td class="tg-9hbo">Dec (dd mm ss)</td>
        <td class="tg-9hbo">Epoch</td>
        <td class="tg-9hbo">V mag</td>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">size</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["obj_name"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["obj_ra"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["obj_dec"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["obj_epoch"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["obj_mag"]; ?>   </td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row["obj_size"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="tg-9hbo">Scientific Justification:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["scient_just"]; ?>   
     </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="tg-9hbo">Submission date:</td>
         <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><?php echo $row["date"]; ?>   </td>
       </tr>


     </table>
 <?php
           /* free results */
           $stmt->free_result();

        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
     ?>
```

Comment: @N Moeini thank you so much for you effort. I m getting syntax error, unexpected '<'error ...please check once again

Comment: Fixed. Test it again.

Comment: @N Moeini its showing error .. Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are already passing `s_no` as a URL parameter `id` to the second page. So the second page needs to pick it up (i.e. `id = $_GET['id']`), then you can use it in SQL query to add `WHERE s_no = id` .

Note: you need to quote any string before you put it in SQL otherwise you will have a SQL injection vulnerability (i.e. anybody on the internet can delete your database). Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Moreover, if `s_no` is unique, you do not need a `while` on the second page - you can fetch a single row (if it exists).

Comment: thank a lot for you response ... im new in php.. how to do that , could you please do it for me. thank a lot

Comment: @explorer104 Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We can help you solve specific problems, but we cannot do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you are opening php tag but not closing it thats why you are getting syntax error

There must be some problem with query statement, make sure that table name and column names are right

```
     $sqli = "SELECT s_no, title_pro, type, cycle, type_pro, thesis, year, 
        proposer, institute, 
        email,present,contact,abstract,status_ongoing,status_file,
       sch_request,no_night,no_night_impossible,just_request,mode_ob,
      brief_descrip,plan,hfosc_b,hfosc_n,hfosc_g,hfosc_s,hesp_r,hesp_o,
    tirspec_b,tirspec_n,tirspec_s,tirspec_c,tirspec_slits,obj_name,obj_ra,
   obj_dec,obj_epoch,obj_mag,obj_size,scient_just,date,   

  status FROM forms WHERE s_no = ?";
```

Comment: @ pranjal k Now the exact error  line is.... "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www line 35", and line 35 is $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); //bind input parameters ... what does it mean please fix it